# Close a form from another form

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I face a problem with a multiple forms application
I have the mainForm and several mdiForms. 
One of these child forms (frmDashboardManager) is open new ownedforms (frmDahboard) outside the mainForm
No I want to check if a frmDahboard is Open and if Yes to close it.
Here is what I have:

```
  Dim fDash As New frmDashboard
  fDash = isDashboardOpen(tempDash) 
  If fDash IsNot Nothing Then
    fDash.Close() 'HERE I GET THE ERROR
  End If


   Private Function isDashboardOpen(ByVal dash As clsDashboard) As frmDashboard

    isDashboardOpen = Nothing
    Try
        'search if Dashboard is already open
        For Each fr As frmDashboard In Me.OwnedForms
            If fr.My_Dashboard.Id = dash.Id Then
                isDashboardOpen = fr
                Exit For
            End If
        Next

    Catch ex As Exception
        gError.GetAppEx(ex, FORM_NAME & ".isDashboardOpen")
    Finally

    End Try

End Function
```

The error that I get is :
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

The crazy thing is that I checked  and isDashboardOpen returns actually a frmDashboard (also that's why fDash.Close() is executed).
Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Using `As New` is very, very wrong.  It creates a 2nd instance of the form, one you cannot see.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found my error.

I disposed twice a user control that I have in frmDashboard.
I corrected that and everything works fine.

Thank you for your time.